# Data sets for digit/letter recognition dimension limitations

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently using a digit data set from UCI repository to run simple Machine Learning techniques on it. The problem is that the dataset is limited to 256dimensions as it is a 16*16 pixels picture. I was wondering if, I have a digit input that is 64*64 pixels, do I need to reduce it to 16*16 or is there a technique I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Every digit recognition algorithm I know will function irrespective of the specific resolution of the image, but if you are truly concerned I suggest you normalize your data ahead of time to a `[0.0, 1.0)` range.

This also works with images that aren't square. For instance, in a 16x16 image 16 would map to 1.0 or 15/16 depending on your preference. This would scale up pretty trivially to arbitrary sized images. If you want some example code I could provide some in your language of choice.

Comment: My data is a 256-number range of zeros and ones. I don't really understand where normalizing fits here O_o

Comment: Usually arrays do not take real valued indices. Thus, some kind of interpolation might be necessary to create images of equal size.

Comment: @TrtTrt well I'm saying that if you are trying to make two arrays comparable you don't have to treat them at totally different things. Tbh I'm not exactly sure what issues there would be with dealing with two different sizes of image files. I generally normalize all the images I deal with and then do a linear interpolation between cells if I need it, but if you could explain exactly what your problem is I could probably help a lot more.

Comment: Using a simple KNN approach, I could compare the my 256-elements array to all the other samples from my training data set. Now my array has only 1 and 0, as each image is thresholded. Where does data normalization fit in here?

Comment: @TrtTrt ooh, had no idea you were doing clustering on this, solution is still data-normalization though. Basically you're going to want to normalize all of your data so that you can effectively access the value of any float e.g.(0.5, 0.25). Then pick some constant granularity and simply "sample" all of your images along a linspace with that many entries e.g. `(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0) X (0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0)` where `X` represents a Cartesian product.

Comment: yes you need to reduce the array to an established length. I'm pretty sure this is just a smooth resampling and threshold

Comment: @jonnydedwards not an exclusive reduction. In fact I'd be more willing to increase more often, but depends on who you ask I suppose.